MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : The nonce in ID Token does not match the SHA256 hash of the raw nonce in the request
I am trying to authenticate into firebase using keycloak as OIDC. I am using authorization code flow of the firebase configuration.
Below is the code that I have written for the same
const access: any = sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    const idToken: any = sessionStorage.getItem('idToken')
    

    const provider = new OAuthProvider('oidc.kc-dev');

    const credential = provider.credential({
      idToken: id_token
      accessToken: access,
    });

    signInWithCredential(getAuth(), credential)
      .then((result: any) => {
        // Get the OAuth access token and ID Token
        const credential1 = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        console.log(credential1);
      })
      .catch((error: any) => {
        // Handle error.
      });


Upon calling this block of code I'm getting following error
"MISSING_OR_INVALID_NONCE : The nonce in ID Token does not match the SHA256 hash of the raw nonce in the request.".
If anyone from the community knows, any guidance would be appreciated.
I have tried adding rawNonce field but it's giving the same error, also I tried disabling the NONCE field from the keycloak dashboard.
